# Cache::has conditional is not running in my code

Tags: php, laravel

I'm very confused with the behaviour of my conditional using Cache::has('variable'). It's supposed to be printed **A** and then **B** OR **C** However it's just **A** what I can see when debugging. Seems like the conditional `if(Cache::has($chat_id)) {` it's skipped at all.What's the problem?

```
if($purpose == 'chat'){
        $action = 2;//chat 
        error_log('A');
        if(Cache::has($chat_id)) {
            error_log('B');
        } else {
            error_log('C');
            $chat = Chat::select('user_id', 'employer_id')->where('_id',$chat_id)->first();
            $user = User::select('email')->where('_id', $chat->user_id)->first();
            $employer = User::select('contact_name')->where('_id', $chat->employer_id)->first();
            $template=EmailTemplate::find('5a7af73cd40aaf098d6f7dc1');
            $find=array('@name@','@employer_name@');           
            $values=array($user->email, $employer->contact_name);        
            $body=str_replace($find,$values,$template->content);
            sendMail($user->email,$body,$template,'Tienes un mensaje de chat nuevo');
            // 1440 minutes = 1 day.
            //Cache::add($chat_id, true, 1440);
        }   
    }
    elseif($purpose == 'interview_cancelled'){
        $action = 3; //interview_cancelled
    }
    elseif($purpose == 'interview'){
        $action = 4; //interview proposed
    }
```

Comment: Have you imported the Facade up top of the file for Cache?

Comment: Sorry I haven't do it. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

Add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;` in the top of the file. I don't know why laravel doesn't show me an import error.